# How to update MySQL ODBC User DSN in VB application?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc, dsn

I developed small dekstop application using VB, and it using MySQL ODBC 5.1 with User DSN to connect the report. After i installed it to the client PC, if i change the connection string (DBServer, DBName, UID, and Password) for MySQL Connection, the User DSN in the machine not changing.

Can anybody help me about the code to update the ODBC user DSN in the application right after we change the connection string?
Thanks in advance for any advice and help.

Comment: There is no code change.  The connection details are stored in the DSN file, which is plain text.  If the database details change then you have to edit that DSN file.  That's the whole point of a DSN: it is independent of any application so you can change it and then any application that uses it will reflect that change without any modification.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to programmatically create / change the Windows User DSN. Is this correct?

Comment: @RobertBaron: yes, that's correct. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, what you need is [SQLConfigDataSource Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function?view=sql-server-2017). See also [Using C# to Add an ODBC System DSN](https://lonewolfonline.net/add-odbc-system-dsn/#), it is in C# but pretty much what you want.